fetch failed Error: self-signed certificate in cerrificate chain in next.js
I cannot send requests with fetch in my Next js project.
When I try with then and catch instead of async await, I see the same error in the terminal. But when using then and catch the page is rendered. In await, the page also gives an error.
First, I made a request to an API that requested an API key, but I got an error. I thought it was a false api-key or a syntax error, then this error in the Terminal caught my attention.
page.jsx:
import React from "react";

const Page = async({ searchParams }) => {

 const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
 const data = await res.json()
console.log(data);

  return <div></div>;
};
export const metadata = {
  title: "Movie App",
};
export default Page;

When I run the project
error:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12345:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)    at async getVersionInfo (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader-webpack.js:215:21)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async HotReloaderWebpack.start (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader-webpack.js:607:28)
    at async startWatcher (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:156:5)  
    at async setupDevBundler (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:775:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async initialize (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:78:30)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\burak.cengiz.BELENCO\Desktop\Web\Next.js\movieapp\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:249:36) {
  cause: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
    code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
  }
}

At the page :
✓ Ready in 3.5s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 3.3s (535 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 500ms (268 modules)
 ⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
    at async Page (./src/app/page.jsx:13:17)
digest: "3320464924"
Cause: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)
    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}
 ⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
    at async Page (./src/app/page.jsx:13:17)
digest: "3320464924"
Cause: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)
    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}
 GET / 500 in 4166ms

I try "next dev --experimental-https"
my package.json:
{
  "name": "movieapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --experimental-https",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}


And i try some following :
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set ca ""
npm update npm -g
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set strict-ssl false -g


What can I do?
